# format a time series as dataframe with julian date

Tags: r

I have a time series tt.txt of daily data from 1st May 1998 to 31 October 2012 in one column as this:

```
    v1
   296.172
   303.24
   303.891
   304.603
   304.207
   303.22
   303.137
   303.343
   304.203
   305.029
   305.099
   304.681
   304.32
   304.471
   305.022
   304.938
   304.298
   304.120
```

Each number in the text file represents the maximum temperature in kelvin for the corresponding day. I want to put the data in 3 columns as follows by adding year, jday, and the value of the data:

```
     year jday MAX_TEMP 
1    1959  325 11.7      
2    1959  326 15.6      
3    1959  327 14.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a vector with dates, we can convert it to 'year' and 'jday' by

```
v1 <- c('May 1998 05', 'October 2012 10')
v2 <- format(as.Date(v1, '%b %Y %d'), '%Y %j')
df1 <- read.table(text=v2, header=FALSE, col.names=c('year', 'jday'))
df1
#  year jday
#1 1998  125
#2 2012  284
```

To convert back from '%Y %j' to 'Date' class

```
df1$date <- as.Date(do.call(paste, df1[1:2]), '%Y %j')
```

#### Update

We can read the dataset with `read.table`.  Create a sequence of dates using `seq` if we know the start and end dates, `cbind` with the original dataset after changing the `format` of 'date' to 'year' and 'julian day'.

```
dat <- read.table('tt.txt', header=TRUE)
date <- seq(as.Date('1998-05-01'), as.Date('2012-10-31'), by='day')
dat2 <- cbind(read.table(text=format(date, '%Y %j'), 
              col.names=c('year', 'jday')),MAX_TEMP=dat[1])
```

Comment: @user3290596  Assuming that the date starts from '1998-05-01' and ends with '2012-10-31', we can create a sequence with `seq`, change the `format` and cbind with the initial dataset

Comment: an error occurred in dat2:  dat2 <- cbind(read.table(text=format(date, '%Y %j'),col.names=c('year', 'jday')),MAX_TEMP=dat[1])
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5298, 5449
looks like length mismatch

Comment: @user3290596  The `seq` created is of a particular length.  If your data i.e. Max_temp didn't have that many elements, it will cause that error.  Without providing much details, it is hard to understand which day you have a missing value for MAX_TEMP

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yday`

```
as.POSIXlt("8 Jun 15", format = "%d %b %y")$yday
```